# pip command is not being recognized

Tags: python, django, pip, setuptools

I am installing python and Django on my shared host server.  I have followed the guide located here to install python and pip

http://flailingmonkey.com/install-django-justhost/

As I've encountered the problem of python never using 3.4.2 I've followed a different guide to install python 3.4.2 which is here

http://joemaller.com/1717/building-python-on-shared-hosting/

After I installed python, I went back to follow the first guide to instlall setup tools and pip.

I've ran all the commands it said and when I look inside python3.4.2/bin folder I see pip pip3 and pip3.4 files there so that tells me that pip was installed.  However whenever I try to use pip instlal Django it says -bash: pip: command not found.  I'm just wondering if I am missing a step somewhere?

Comment: have you tried pip3?

Comment: I have just now, did not work.

Comment: what does `which pip` output? Also `which python3`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham absolutely nothing

Comment: Ok then you don't seem to have python3. What os?

Comment: its on justhost.com  shared hosting  when I type python --version it says 3.4.2

Comment: did you add the export line?

Comment: I followed the guide.  I provided that guide in my initial post, its the second link.  And yes I added the export line, otherwise the python --version would now should as 3.4.2 right?  or that doesn't matter?

Comment: and do `source ~/.bashrc` after?

Comment: yes I have done source ~/.bashrc after but I'll go do it again

Comment: same results as before

Comment: what happens when you type python in bash?

Comment: python mode then starts and it says it is using 3.4.2 python.

Comment: have you tried using get-pip.py to install pip?

Comment: `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` `python get-pip.py`

Comment: Just try that and see if it works

Comment: I tried those 2 commands just now and it downloaded the pip and then when I tried get-pip.py it said aleady up-top-date: pip.in ..path

Comment: what does `sudo which python` output?

Comment: sudo: unable to get stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudeors sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: ok so you don't have sudo permissions. where did it say pip was installed?

Comment: in opt/python 3.4.2/bin

Comment: what does `opt/bin/pip freeze` output ?

Comment: nothing and I modified the path so it points to where pip is

Comment: `opt/bin/pip install django` actually runs?

Comment: yeah it did, do I have to create an alias?

Comment: show me the output of `cat .bashrc | grep export`

Comment: interesting, when I tried to install flup with that commend it attempted but it failed: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /var/tmp/pip-build-_wed012f/flup

Comment: not all packages are compatible with python3, what was the main error

Comment: output of cat command is export PATH=$HOME/opt/bin:$PATH   how do I see the main error here?  What am I looking for?

Comment: I just wanted to see the command exactly as it is in your file. What  shows for /opt.. when you  `echo $PATH`

Comment: so `/home1/azularis/opt/bin/pip install foo` works? Works as in attempts to install

Comment: no it doesn't I answered prematurely.

Comment: /home1/azularis/opt/python3.4.2/bin/pip install flup   this attempts to install it

Comment: try adding `/home1/azularis/opt/python3.4.2/bin` to your path, exactly as you have done the other in bashrc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72485/discussion-between-bagzli-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is set incorrectly so adding so add the following to .bashrc:

```
export PATH=$HOME/opt/python3.4.2/bin:$PATH
```

And then `source ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to write this in consol to install pip

```
easy_install pip
```

Comment: interesting, when I tried that it said it did not have write access to the directory

Comment: this tries to install in /usr... which requires root permissions

Comment: I don't think I have root permissions, this is on a shared host.